# cordova-3.4.0 doesn't copy plugins to platform folder

Tags: cordova-3

I recently installed cordova 3.4.0 in my system through node js

- The cli is working fine but i am facing these problems.
- Some plugins alone not adding inside the platforms.

  For Ex:

  - I added the plugin like
    **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation**
  - the plugin is adding in the ProjectName/plugins folder.
  - After that i gave
    **cordova build android**
  - Now the plugins are not adding inside android platform.

I dont know what the issue was. The plugins like dialog, device are working fine. 
I am facing these issues for the plugins like
**geolocation, console, camera**.

Thanks guys in advance....

Can any one tell me the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the solution. the geolocation plugin for android removed from their git because, we can use the pre defined api for geolocation which is present in the HTML5.

It means, we can use 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method directly to find the location using javascript.

But what confusing me is, if we can use web api, why they didn't removed for ios?

Answer (score 0):

In cordova 3.4, initially you have to add all the required platforms. After that if you install plugins it will be reflected in all platforms.